How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{2n\pi}}|\sin(x^2)|dx$?
I am trying to compute the limit:$$\lim_n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{2n\pi}}|\sin(x^2)|dx$$My try:Let $t=x^2$,$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{2n\pi}}|\sin(x^2)|dx&=\frac1{\sqrt n}\int_{n\pi}^{2n \pi}\frac{|\sin t|}{2\sqrt t}dt\\&=\frac1{\sqrt n}\int_{0}^{n \pi}\frac{|\sin t|}{2\sqrt {t+n\pi}}dt\\&=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin t|}{2\sqrt {t+n\pi}}dt
\end{align}$$Since $\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}|\sin t|dt=2$,we can conclude that$$\frac1{\sqrt{(k+n+1)\pi}}\le \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin t|}{2\sqrt {t+n\pi}}dt\le\frac1{\sqrt{(k+n)\pi}}$$Therefore:$$\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{(k+n+1)\pi}}\le \frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin t|}{2\sqrt {t+n\pi}}dt\le\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{(k+n)\pi}}$$
On intuition,for me,I think the inequlity above is "close" enough.But I find it hard to evaluate the sum:$\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{(k+n)\pi}}$
Any help would be appreciated.

Hint: $$
\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {(k + n)\pi } }}}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {(k/n + 1)\pi } }}}  \to \frac{1}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_0^1 {\frac{{{\rm d}x}}{{\sqrt {x + 1} }}} ,
$$ and similarly for the other sum.

Oops!I didn't notice it yet.Thanks!

As an option: for the periodic function $g(x)$ with the period $,T$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bg(nx)f(x)dx=\frac1T\int_0^Tg(t)dt\int_a^bf(x)dx$$
Using this,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{2n\pi}}|\sin(x^2)|dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\sqrt n}2\int_\pi^{2\pi}|\sin(nt)|\frac{dt}{\sqrt t}$$
$$=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^\pi|\sin x|dx\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=2\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt \pi}$$

Let $I_n$ be the integral. Then
$$I_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{|\sin u|\,du}{2\sqrt{u + (k+n)\pi}} = \frac12\int_{0}^\pi \left(\frac1{n\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k+\frac{u}{\pi}}{n}+1}}\right) |\sin (u)|du$$
The function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, and for all $k \in [0,n-1]$, $u \in [0,\pi]$,
$$\frac{k + \frac{u}{\pi}}{n} \in \left[\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n}\right].$$
Thus
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k+\frac{u}{\pi}}{n}+1}} = \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}}\,dx = [2 \sqrt{1 + x}]_{0}^1 = 2 (\sqrt{2}-1)$$
This should be enough to help :)

This is too advanced. Just written for your curiosity.
$$S_n=\frac{1}{{\sqrt {n \pi} }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {k + n } }}}  =\frac{1}{{\sqrt {n \pi} }}\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},n\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},2 n\right)\right)$$ where appears  the Hurwitz zeta function.
The asymptotics
$$\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},p\right)=-2\sqrt p \, \Bigg(1-\frac{1}{4 p}-\frac{1}{48 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right) \Bigg)$$ Applying it twice and finishing with Taylor
$$\Delta_n=\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},n\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},2 n\right)$$ $$\Delta_n=2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \sqrt{n}_,\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2} \,n}+\frac{2+3 \sqrt{2}}{192\, n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)   \Bigg)$$ Then, $S_n$, its limit and a good approximation for finite $n$ (for $n=2$, the relative error is $0.015$%).
